# view-source: having the incorrect JSON rendering ToString() C# MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, json, asp.net-mvc, tostring

While trying to fetch the db table column value which looks like:

```
{   "@context":        }
```

The front end web application  view source is rendering as

```
{   &quot;@context&quot;:   }
```

which should be like

```
{   "@context":        }
```

In Visual Studio Quick watch I could see the fetched value is looking good.
But while rending it is having hyper text characters.

Below is the Front end code,

```
agentModel.JSON = Convert.ToString(agentItem.GetValue("JSON"));
ViewBag.JSON = agentModel.JSON;
<script type="application/ld+json">
    @ViewBag.JSON
</script>
```

Have also tried agentItem.GetValue("JSON").ToString(), but no help.

Please advise how to fix this so that it prints the correct character quot in the front end view source.

Answer (score 1):

To display the data without the HTML encoding, you can use @Html.Raw( ), which is part of the HTML Helper:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg480740(v=vs.118).aspx

In your case, try writing: `@Html.Raw(ViewBag.JSON)`